# shap plot explantion for classification nn model

Tags: plot, deep-learning, interpreter, shap, violin-plot

i used shap to interpret my classification NN model(2 target) and and visualize my model by shap.plot (vilion plot ,bar plot ,force plot ) but i have issues to understand  these plots !

in my model i have two target (1 for coffee shop & 0 for florist)

and there is 10 feature that has to interpret effect of them on model output

```
shap.plots.violin(shap_values, feature_names=feat_names)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkM0G.png)

in the vilion plot there is horizental plot which get into 2 side or has 2 color or has tall post in the wide side of plot that confusing me

for exaple if i want know feature 9 has more effect on coffeeshop or florist ,what should i de !?

and here is barplot

```
shap.plots.bar(shap_values.cohorts(2).abs.mean(0))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xagr.png)

**and in the end how can we show the effect of 1 features on multipleclass??**

Comment: It is called "violin plot" - based on its typical shape.